# angularjs show/hide progressbar on ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I want to show/hide progress bar at the time of service call(AJAX) in angularjs. I am expecting this should be common for all service call.

Comment: What have you try so far ?

Comment: What is the question/problem you are facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ngProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)

```
NProgress.start()  //shows the progress bar
NProgress.set(0.4) //sets a percentage
NProgress.inc()  //increments by a little
NProgress.done() //completes the progress
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) you have to just include this module as dependency and you are done.